# How to lazy evaluate the value in the one-line if-else python statement?

Tags: python-2.7, lazy-evaluation

This is the python code

```
current_task.request.task if current_task is not None else None
```

`current_task` could be `None` but python evaluates the statement before checking the condition. That's why I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Is there anyway to lazy evaluate `current_task.request.task`?

**Update**

I think I was confused by the output and the type of the current_task.

```
>>print type(current_task)
>><class 'celery.local.Proxy'>

>>print current_task
>>None                  #obviously it calls __str__() to dump the None instead for the current case.
```

Thanks in advance and your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Running that line on 2.5.1, 2.7.4, and 3.3.0 all produce lazy results just as you want.

Comment: @jwodder I am using python 2.7.5. Updated it. But it doesn't work on my local.

Comment: Upshot: yes, one-line if-else **is lazy**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is `current_task` is set to something, just not set to `None`.

Your expression is equivalent to

```
if current_task is not None:
   current_task.request.task 
else:
  None
```

So `current_task.request` will be accessed if `current_task` is set to **any** value other than `None`

Alternatively, I believe you could rewrite this expression as

```
current_task and current_task.request.task
```

Python will proceed to the second half of the expression so long as `current_task` is not any of the following values

- `None`
- `False`
- zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`
- any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`
- any empty mapping, for example, `{}`
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer `0` or bool value `False`.

---

Based on your update, this feels a little ugly, but you could do this

```
current_task.request.task if current_task.__str__() != 'None' else None
```

Comment: What values are there that aren't `None` yet are of `NoneType`?

Comment: Something else to **try**:  if the proxy displays itself as `None`, it may compare equal to `None`, so try testing `current_task != None`.  That's very different from `is not` testing.

Answer (score 2):

Something is confused here!

```
>>> 1/0 if 0 else 12
12
```

See?  No `ZeroDivisionError`.  `... if ... else ...` already short-circuits.

Or:

```
>>> current_task = None
>>> print current_task.request.task if current_task is not None else None
None
```

So I don't believe you ;-)  Post more details, like an actual terminal session, as I did for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work as is. This works for example.

```
a = 'String'
a.lower() if a else None
a = None
a.lower() if a else None
```